# How can I exit a program asking for inputs in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am taking a course and I have the programs run in a loop so you can easily exit by entering "Quit". I am running into trouble working with arrays. This has the user type in sentences and then at the end shows the user what they typed. I want to have the program check each input the user types in and if it is "Quit", I want to exit the program. I am new to Java so looking for something that is within my understanding without using a break if possible.

I have attempted to use a boolean in my while loop to quit when it is set to false.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String [] Responses = new String [10];
    boolean ExitLoop = true;

    do  
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter sentence " + (i+1) + ": ");

            Responses[n] = Input.nextLine();
            if (Responses[n] == "Quit")
            {
                ExitLoop = false;
            }

            n++;
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Sentence " + (j+1) + " " + Responses[j]);
        }

   }
    while (ExitLoop);
}
```

Comment: On a sidenote, see [comparing strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: i think better way is throwing exception. `System.exit()` is bad way

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Why would you ever throw an exception when nothing is wrong? If the application is supposed to be exiting at that time, there is no need for an exception.

Comment: Hi @user121582 if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Also, if no answer has helped you, think about adding a comment to signal for more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To exit the application you can call the following line from anywhere.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Integrated into you code it would look like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter sentence " + (i+1) + ": ");

    Responses[n] = Input.nextLine();
    if (Responses[n].equals("Quit"))
    {
        System.exit(0); //add this to exit the application
    }

    n++;
}
```

If you wanted to keep separation of concerns you could make a method that exits the application.

```
public void ExitApplication()
{
    //you can add pre-exit checks and other items here
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Then you could simply call the method from inside you loop.

```
if (Responses[n].equals("Quit"))
{
    ExitApplication();
}
```

Comment: the bad point. string values don't compare with `==` operator. `exit()` is one of the worst methods.

Comment: Great point on the `==` operator. I wasn't meaning to alter the OP's code too much, but just give the answer on how to exit.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko updated my answer to reflect your feedback

Comment: What's wrong with `exit()`, especially if the program is just asking for basic I/O?

Answer (score 0):

The '==' operator only checks if the strings refer to the same memory location, which they do not. Try using the string.equals() method for comparing the actual string values.

```
if (Responses[n].equals("Quit")) {
    ExitLoop = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one variable for iteration, and you need to use equals for comparing string.
Try that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final int countSentences = 10;
    final String[] sentences = new String[countSentences];
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < countSentences; i++) {    
        System.out.println("Please enter sentence "+(i+1)+": ");    
        sentences[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        if (sentences[i].equals("Quit")) System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int j = 0; j < countSentences; j++)
        System.out.println("Sentence "+(j+1)+" "+sentences[j]);
}
```